# How to compare two arrays in Laravel populate select list with matched and unmatched values

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Good day guys. I have two arrays and want to compare them to find common elements. If there are matching values those values should obtain the `selected attribute` on the select element, otherwise those values that are not matching should not have the selected attribute.

These are my two arrays:

**dd($role->permissions);**

```
array:3 [▼
  "edit-student" => "true"
  "create-student" => "true"
  "create-guardian" => "true"
]
```

**dd($permissions);**

```
array:5 [▼
  "create-student" => "true"
  "edit-student" => "true"
  "delete-student" => "true"
  "create-guardian" => "true"
  "delete-guardian" => "true"
]
```

This is the code in my view:

```
 <select class="form-control permissions" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;" name="permissions[]" >
  @foreach($permissions as $key => $val)
    @foreach($role->permissions as $roleKey => $roleVal)
      @if($key == $roleKey)
        <option value="{{$val}}" selected="">{{$key}}</option>
      @else
        <option value="{{$val}}">{{$key}}</option>
      @endif
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
</select>
```

What happens is this returns the right selected values, but there are duplicate of those selected values in the select list, and that is what I'm trying to avoid.
Here is a picture that shows what I'm talking about.

[image]

Here in the picture you see how the values are being repeated even though the right values are being selected. How can I avoid such from happening? I know the problem is with my logic in the view but don't know how to refactor it. Any help guys? Will appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop is wrong. You should iterate over all elements an if they are in your role permission array, they will be selected.

```
<select class="form-control permissions" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;" name="permissions[]" >
  @foreach($permissions as $key => $val)
        <option value="{{$val}}" {{ isset($role->permissions[$key]) ? 'selected=\"\"' : ''}}">{{$key}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Getting this error: `Call to a member function contains() on array`

Comment: thought it was a collection, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Before you put the arrays into the control, merge and unique them;

```
$finalArray = array_unique(array_merge($role->permissions, $permissions));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you write an `option` anyway in each iteration of the second `array`. You would nee to use a `$found` variable, which would be initialized to `false` just after the first `foreach` and set it to `true` inside the second `foreach` if a match is found. You will not need to generate an `option` for each iteration of the inner `foreach`. You will need to check for the value of `$found` after the second `foreach` and if it is `true`, then the item will be `selected`. If not, then the item will not be `selected`.

EDIT:

An example:

```
 <select class="form-control permissions" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;" name="permissions[]" >
  <?php foreach($permissions as $key => $val) { ?>
    <?php
    $found = isset($role->permissions[$key]);
      if($found) ?>
        <option value="{{$val}}" selected="">{{$key}}</option> <?php
      else ?>
        <option value="{{$val}}">{{$key}}</option> <?php
  } ?>
</select>
```

Note that we can avoid the inner iteration using `isset`.